# Show that $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_2)$ is a metric space.

Tags: general-topology

Show that $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_2)$ is a metric space where $d_2((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2}$.

I was able to show that $d_2$ is nonnegative and symmetric, but I'm having troubles with the triangle inequality. That is, showing $d_2((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))+d_2((y_1,y_2),(z_1,z_2))\ge d_2((x_1,x_2),(z_1,z_2))$.

Can someone help?

Comment: Use Minkowski's inequality: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality

Comment: @Voldemort Is that necessary? I'd feel more comfortable just using algebraic manipulation.

Comment: No- definitely not necessary. I think you can just square both sides and do algebraic manipulations to get the fact (I had once done it- long time ago). However, it's late in the night, and I didn't want to do the algebra :)
Try squaring both sides.

Comment: I've tried doing this, but so far I'm just getting "stuff" $\ge -2x_1z_1-2x_2z_2$.

Comment: Perhaps this could help: http://www.math.utah.edu/~kapovich/TEA/2003/tri.pdf ?

Comment: Defining $a_k=x_k-y_k$, $b_k = y_k-z_k$ and $c_k=z_k-x_k$ and using $a_k+b_k+c_k=0$ later may reduce writing a lot if you want to do algebraic manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

Brute force algebra should work, given sufficient skill and diligence.

Alternatively, the triangle inequality follows immediately from the cosine rule, which has [umpteen possible proofs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines), and the fact that $\cos\theta \le 1$.

Comment: Hmm... I'm still having troubles. Perhaps I can ask my professor in the morning.